# How to extract dependency versions with jenkins pipeline

Tags: maven, jenkins, gradle

How can i extract dependencys ant their versions from pom.xml for maven projects and from build.gradle file for gradle projects.

For maven i can use readMavenPom to read in the pom file. But how can i get all the dependencies and their versions?

How can i read and use the build.gradle file in jenkins pipeline?

This will be used to fail a build on master branch if there is a dependency in snapshot version.

Comment: You can use `mvn dependency:list`

Comment: can i pipe it into somesor of variable for processing inside jenkins pipeline ?

Comment: To check for SNAPSHOT versions in your maven build there is a solution via maven-enforcer-plugin but for Gradle I can't tell.